# Method to combine or use multiple post-quantum cryptographic libraries?

Tags: quantum-computing

A project I'm contributing to at the moment is having trouble working with two different cryptographic libraries. The purpose of the work is to explore post-quantum security, and is increasing as a priority in the team (especially after [Apple's iMessage updating to PQ3](https://security.apple.com/blog/imessage-pq3/)). Is there a specific library or bridge to allow such collaboration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the abstraction needs of your project, [Sandwich from SandboxAQ](https://github.com/sandbox-quantum/sandwich) is built for the purpose of unifying crytographic libraries. In their own words [from the github repo](https://github.com/sandbox-quantum/sandwich):

> Sandwich is a multi-platform, multi-language, open-source library that provides a simple unified API for developers to use (multiple) cryptographic libraries in their applications.

We evaluated it as an option merging a legacy Python and a newer Rust project and it looked promising. Some breaking changes as it is still in beta.